# Inserting Lat/Long spatial extensions into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, gis, latitude-longitude

I'm wanting to put polygons into a MySQL database and then with PHP be able to query if a latitude/longitiude point is inside the polygon.

Any pointers here.  Never done anything like this yet.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL supports Spacial columns and functions using an extension which is quite often installed by default.

[MySQL Reference for spacial features](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html)

[How to use MySQL Spacial extension](http://howto-use-mysql-spatial-ext.blogspot.com/)

Comment: These features were significantly upgraded in MySQL 5.6.1 - they [moved beyond MBR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries). The second link was written **before** that happened, the first link is to the latest documentation (**after** that happened)